# ASP.NET Membership - LDAP Authentication Against Apache DS

Tags: asp.net, authentication, ldap

I am trying to set up a custom ASP.NET membership provider to authenticate using LDAP and Apache DS.  This is what my web.config entry looks like:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
<add name="DefaultMembershipProvider"
     type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
     connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
     connectionProtection="None"
     connectionUsername="uid=myid, O=this domain"
     connectionPassword="mypwd"
     attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
     enableSearchMethods="True" />
```

I am not having much luck here, probably owing to the fact that I have no idea what I am doing.  I am hoping someone can at least verify I am headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider for LDAP, it requires a real ActiveDirectory server.  Unless Apache DS emulates AD, you won't be able to use this.

You're going to have do a custom membership provider.  THere's a working example here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/970391.aspx/1